# How To Format Number In C++?

Tags: c++

I want to format my output in C++ in #.###.### type. 
Ex: I have an int number called `num = 123456789`
Now I want to format it to `123.456.789` as my output.
How can I do that in C++? Thanks for your help

**Ex1:** 
Input:

```
int a = 12345
```

Expected output:

```
a = 12.345
```

**Ex2:** 
Input:

```
int a = 123456
```

Expected output:

```
a = 123.456
```

**Ex3:**
Input:

```
int a = 1234567
```

Expected output:

```
a = 1.234.567
```

Comment: This is a homework type question! Please edit your question and tell us what you've already tried. So people can help you better.

Comment: It seems that I have no idea for it! Thanks to Jerry's answer, now I know std::cout.imbue(std::locale("")) can solve this issue as I expected. Btw, any suggestion from you guys? I'm glad to know more

Comment: Well, actually, the first thought to me is converting this number to string type and use a loop from the last index to the first one and count every three characters, I'll insert a dot and after that, print this number as a string. However, I think it's not a smart way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normally do it by setting the proper locale before printing it out. Most of the time, the "proper" locale isn't the one you (the programmer) has selected, but rather the one selected by the user. To get that, you use a locale without a name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() { 
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    std::vector<int> values { 123456789, 12345, 123456, 1234567 };

    for (auto v : values)
        std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

On my machine (configured for English/US locale) this produces output like this:

```
123,456,789
12,345
123,456
1,234,567
```

If your machine is configured for a locale that uses `.` instead of `,` as a thousands separator, that's what you should get. If you need to ensure you get that regardless of the user's wishes (think twice, but...) you can do that by specifying a locale explicitly. For example, if I use: `std::cout.imbue(std::locale("DE"));`, I get output like you asked for:

```
123.456.789
12.345
123.456
1.234.567
```

Consult your compiler's documentation for information about the available locales, and the names to use for them.